# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when trying to access dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

test_ds is a dataset of shape

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 256, 256, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>.
```

When i try to fetch data using for loop it worked.

```
for image_batch,label_batch in test_ds.take(1):
```

but when i try to fetch using following line of code it is throwing error

```
image_batch,label_batch=test_ds.take(1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Could someone let me know the issue here.

Comment: In the first case you iterate over some kind of list (each element of the list is converted to 2 variables) But in the 2nd you convert the one list into 2 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tf.data.Dataset` is an iterator. You need to iterate over it in order to access its elements. Try:

```
image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(test_ds.take(1)))
```